# Error was: No module named Random

Tags: python, django, random

Python 2.4.3, when I run python via the command line and import random, it works just fine. When I run a django based website "python manage.py runserver", the server starts up fine, but as soon as I load a page, it tosses me this error.

I really have no clue how to fix this. I've done some searching, random is core to python, the import I tried from the python interpreter seems to indicated to me that it's working. However, it's not working when running the website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
~P

Comment: apologies it is "Random"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error is exactly "No module named Random", then you've written `import Random` when you really meant `import random`. There is no module in the Python standard library called `Random`. Module names are case sensitive in Python. If that doesn't solve your problem, please show us some code from whatever module imports `random`

Comment: you know that really helps. It is import random in the code, which is where I assumed it was getting stuck, but it was actually getting stuck on import Crypto.Random as Random. I will investigate this further and ask another question if I have to. Thanks!

Comment: @Prescott if that's the case, you might not have pycrypto installed.

Comment: I had to install it for Crypto.PublicKey - but maybe it missed something